# Thoughts on using Nginx to proxy webrequests to a .Net HttpListener based Json service

Tags: c#, .net, nginx, httplistener

I am making a webservice that only needs to serve json and it needs to be scalable.

I have gotten the impression that Nginx is a more scalable webserver than IIS 7.5 and that it is extremely simple to manage compared to IIS. Also, Nginx can very easily be used to load balance among several json services, using the upstream module.

As I only need to serve json I feel that ASP.NET and IIS i way overkill. I just need some very simple routing and a simple authcookie mechanism I easily can write myself.

Right now I am using MVC3 but feels it is to bloated when I only servce Json, and I am very annoyed by the facts that I am having to write custom Auth attributes to make a default deny policy, having to make a HttpModule to hack around WindowsForms authentication's default redirection of unauthorized requests and in general needs to read and learn a lot to stay in control of the framework. I have also considered WCF but my prev. experience with this was that there was to much bloat and configuration for my needs and to much stuff to know about to stay in control.

I prefer simplicity and want to avoid "framework overhead" when I just need to handle some Http for a simple, fast and scalable async json service. So I am considering a setup like this:

- An Nginx webserver on a linux box that load balances among and proxies webrequests to async json services.
- The json services are written as Windows Services using HttpListener to do Async handling of web reqests.

What are your thoughts about this architecture?

EDIT: Actually I think it would be more performant using fastcgi from nginx to the windows services instead of proxying http prequests? What are your thoughts?

Comment: are you tied to use a .net implementation or are you free to choose another programming environmental? Because it looks like .net is a bit overkill for this. May be http://nodejs.org/ fits better to your requirements.

Comment: I am tied to the C# language, because a prefer a statically typed and compiled language. Actually I find that writing a large server in node takes too long time compared to doing it in C#, because it is much faster to debug C# code because you get so much help from the compiler and resharper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just implement an ASHX - basically a [`IHttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) for IIS which scales really well and most of the issues you describe just "go away"... it gives you full control over the whole request/response processing... for a nice tutorial see http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx

Comment: Thanks for the link. Good to know about, but for my current problem I would like to separate the webserver from the application. I would like to hear from someone having tried something like what I described.

Comment: @ssn (whether you employ nginx for loadbalancing doesn't have any impact on implementation) - having implemented some HttpListener-based Windows Service myself I am not sure what exactly you want to know... perhaps you could elaborate...

Comment: Ok. Basically I would like to know if the overall architecture sounds ok, given that I don't want to use IIS or ASP.NET. Another thing I am considering is whether to use fastcgi or http proxying (with httplistener) from NGINX to the windows services. I assume that using fastcgi will be more efficient because persistent TCP connections would be used. Am I right in that assumption?

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that it would be more than sufficient to configure a simple web application that  has one request handler that returns the relevant Json response.

You may want to look at optimising the ASP .NET pipeline. You can read more about this and other ASP .NET optimisations [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/10ASPNetPerformance.aspx). If the request handling is lightweight from a processing perspective, you may also want to bump up the thread limits. This is also covered in the article referenced.

From an Nginx point of view, you may want to check that number of worker threads matches your CPU count.

Hope this helps.

Comment: By simple web application you mean an ASP.NET web application ?

Comment: Yeah. For your purposes, I'm not sure whether there would be a measurable difference when comparing MVC vs. Webforms.